# How does one draw a cylindrical shell in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I am trying to illustrate the disk and shell methods for computing the volume of solids of revolution. I was able to use the following code to create a typical approximating disk when the revolution is about the *x-axis*. I am stuck on how to create a typical approximating shell when the same region is revolved about the *y-axis*. How might I achieve this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex,x=1.5cm,y=0.8cm]
        \fill[fill=green,opacity=0.5] (1,0) -- plot[domain=1:4] (\x,{sqrt(2*(\x)+1))}) -- (4,0);
        \fill[fill=green,opacity=0.5] (1,0) -- plot[domain=1:4] (\x,{-sqrt(2*(\x)+1))}) -- (4,0);
        \draw[-,thick,domain=-.2:4.5,samples=100] plot (\x,{sqrt(2*(\x)+1))}) node[right] {\footnotesize $y=f(x)$};
        \draw[-,thick,domain=-.2:4.5,samples=100] plot (\x,{-sqrt(2*(\x)+1))});
        \draw[fill=gray!50] (4,0) circle [x radius =.2 , y radius =3];
        \draw[fill=gray!50] (1,0) circle [x radius =.2 , y radius =1.732050808];
        \draw[fill=red!40] (2.3,0) circle [x radius =.2 , y radius =2.449489743];
        \fill[red!40] (2.3,-2.449489743) rectangle (2.7,2.449489743);
        \draw[fill=red!40] (2.7,0) circle [x radius =.2 , y radius =2.449489743];
        \draw (2.3,2.449489743) -- (2.7,2.449489743);
        \draw (2.3,-2.449489743) -- (2.7,-2.449489743);
        \draw[<->] (2.3,-2.6) -- (2.7,-2.6) node[below, midway] {\footnotesize $\Delta x$};
        \draw[<->] (2.9,0) -- (2.9,2.449489743) node[right, midway]  {\footnotesize $R$};
        \draw[->,thick] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[above] {\footnotesize $x$};
        \draw[->,thick] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[below right]{\footnotesize $y$};
        \draw[-] (1,3pt) -- (1,-3pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $a$};
        \draw[-] (4,3pt) -- (4,-3pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $b$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert to understand how it should look like. It would be helpful, if you could add an example picture for Illustration.

Comment: This link shows examples:http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/VolumeWithCylinder.aspx

Comment: The pgfplots manual on CTAN shows following example, which may be starting point for 3D graphics: % Preamble: \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.15} 1 −0.5 0 0.5 \begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}[view={60}{30}] \addplot3 [ surf,shader=flat, samples=20, domain=-1:0,y domain=0:2*pi, z buffer=sort, ] ( {sqrt(1-x^2) * cos(deg(y))}, {sqrt(1-x^2) * sin(deg(y))}, x ); \end{axis} \end{tikzpicture}

Comment: @DJJerome So my answer was not what you were looking for?

Comment: @Cragfelt unfortunately, your solution doesn’t highlight the three components of a cylindrical shell: its radius, height, and thickness.

Comment: As you could see, I have just adjusted the plot to y-axis accordingly to the information on your code, since you did not specify anything else besides a link. What else do I need to include to my plot in order to meet the spectations of your question?

Comment: @Cragfelt see figure 3 in this document: http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Concepts%20and%20Contexts/upfiles/3c3-Volums-CylinShells_Stu%20.pdf

Comment: @DJJerome Ok. See the update below.

Comment: @Cragfelt ok, you’re getting closer. The interval [a, b] is on the x-axis, not the y-axis. Take the same region defined in the question, and revolve it about the y-axis. Only the axis of revolution changes. So, the shell extends from the curve down to the x-axis.

Answer (score 6):

Practically you need to switch all the coordinates and domains, and make some other minor changes. Also obtaining the function in terms of `x` algebraically.

This is the output according to your code, where revolution is about the **x-axis**

[image]

and this is output after changes, regarding revolution around **y-axis**.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
            scale=1,
            >=latex,
            x=0.8cm,
            y=1.5cm,
            ]
    \fill[fill=green, opacity=0.5] (-3,4) -- plot[domain=-3:3](\x,{0.5*(\x*\x-1)}) -- (3,4);
    \fill[fill=white] (-1.732050808,1) -- plot[domain=-1.732050808:1.732050808] (\x,{0.5*(\x*\x-1)}) -- (1.732050808,1); 

    \draw[-,thick, domain=-3.2:3.2, samples=100] plot (\x,{0.5*(\x*\x-1)}) node[right] {\footnotesize $y=f(x)$};
    \draw[fill=gray!50] (0,4) circle [y radius =.2 , x radius =3];
    \draw[fill=gray!50] (0,1) circle [y radius =.2 , x radius =1.732050808];
    \draw[fill=red!60] (0,2.3) circle [y radius =.2 , x radius =2.449489743];
    \fill[red!60] (-2.449489743,2.3) rectangle (2.449489743,2.7);
    \draw[fill=red!40] (0,2.7) circle [y radius =.2 , x radius =2.449489743];
    \draw (2.449489743,2.3) -- (2.449489743,2.7);
    \draw (-2.449489743,2.3) -- (-2.449489743,2.7);
    \draw[<->] (-2.6,2.3) -- (-2.6,2.7) node[left, midway] {\footnotesize $\Delta x$};
    \draw[<->] (0,2.9) -- (2.449489743,2.9) node[above, midway]  {\footnotesize $R$};
    \draw[->, thick] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node[above] {\footnotesize $x$};
    \draw[->, thick] (0,-1) -- (0,5) node[below right]{\footnotesize $y$};
    \draw[-] (-3pt,1) -- (3pt,1) node[right] {\footnotesize $a$};
    \draw[-] (-3pt,4) -- (3pt,4) node[right] {\footnotesize $b$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**UPDATE**

According to your feedback in comments, I could figured out how to replicate a shell as the document provided, and made respective changes to the original drawing. Maybe now it meets your specs.

[image]
This is the code

```
\documentclass[border=4mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\footnotesize

    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
            scale=1,
            >=stealth,
            x=0.8cm,
            y=1.5cm,
            ]
    \tikzset{cyl/.style = {thick,color=red!60}}
    \tikzset{ellip/.style = {gray!80, shading=axis, top color=gray!80, right color=gray!20, thick}}

    %\fill[fill=green, opacity=0.4] (-3,4) -- plot[domain=-3:3](\x,{0.5*(\x*\x-1)}) -- (3,4);
    %\fill[fill=white] (-1.732050808,1) -- plot[domain=-1.732050808:1.732050808] (\x,{0.5*(\x*\x-1)}) -- (1.732050808,1); 

    % Parabola
    \draw[-, blue, thick, domain=-3.2:3.2, samples=100] plot (\x,{0.5*(\x*\x-1)}) node[right] {$y=f(x)$};

    % Ellipses & Cyllinder
    \shadedraw[ellip] (0,4) circle [y radius =.2, x radius =3];
    \shadedraw[ellip] (0,1) circle [y radius =.2, x radius =1.732050808];
    \shadedraw[cyl, shading=axis, top color=red!50, right color=red!15] (0,2.3) circle [y radius =.2, x radius =2.449489743];
    \shadedraw[cyl, draw=none, shading=axis, top color=red!50, right color=red!15] (-2.449489743,2.3) rectangle (2.449489743,2.7);
    \draw[cyl, fill=red!30] (0,2.7) circle [y radius =.2, x radius =2.449489743];
    \shadedraw[cyl, shading=axis, top color=red!15, right color=red!50] (0,2.7) circle [y radius =.16, x radius =2.25];
    \draw[cyl, opacity=0.7, dashed] (0,2.3) circle [y radius =.16, x radius =2.25];
    \draw[cyl, opacity=0.7, dashed] (0,2.3) circle [y radius =.2, x radius =2.449489743];
    \draw[dashed] (2.449489743,0) -- (2.449489743,2.7);
    \draw[dashed] (2.25,0) -- (2.25,2.7);
    \draw[cyl, opacity=0.7, dashed] (-2.25,2.3) -- (-2.25,2.7);
    \draw[cyl] (2.449489743,2.3) -- (2.449489743,2.7);
    \draw[cyl] (-2.449489743,2.3) -- (-2.449489743,2.7);

    % Dimensions
    \draw (-3pt,1) -- (3pt,1) node[right] {$a$};
    \draw (-3pt,4) -- (3pt,4) node[right] {$b$};
    \draw (-57.5pt,2.95) -- node[anchor=south] {$\overline{x}_i$} (-49pt,2.95);
    \draw (-2.449489743,2.5) -- (-2.449489743,3);
    \draw (-2.25,2.7) -- (-2.25,3);
    \node at (2.25,0) [below right] {$x_i$};
    \node at (2.449489743,0) [below left] {$x_{i-1}$};
    \draw[<->, >=stealth] (-2.6,2.3) -- (-2.6,2.7) node[left, midway] {$\Delta y$};

    % Axes
    \draw[thick] (0,-1) -- (0,2.1);
    \draw[thick, dashed] (0,2.1) -- (0,2.535);
    \draw[->, thick] (0,2.535) -- (0,5) node[below right] {$y$};
    \draw[->, thick] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node[above] {$x$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```