# How to recreate the shell method diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to recreate the following diagram with `Tikz`. I tried to use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404849/65856) but I'm left in veil.

[image]

Comment: @Zarko come here or I will answer this one in four years.

Comment: Please do not get me wrong. However, if you want to get a more detailed answer (which is, of course, completely justified) it could, from my point of view, make more sense to to clarify the question more. Do you want a complete reproduction of the screen shot? Do you want to have some more conceptual information on how to produce such plots? If so, what precisely do you want to get more information for?

Comment: Yes, i want to reproduce the diagram. But anything close to it appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

This is a start, maybe.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[hide axis,colormap={cw}{color=(white) color=(blue)},
    clip=false,width=12cm,
    axis equal,view={10}{0},point meta={abs(z+0.2*y)},
    mantle/.style={surf,shader=interp,domain=0:2,domain y=#1:#1+180,samples y=37,
    mesh/ordering=y varies,,opacity=0.6},
    declare function={delta=-0.1;phi1=90;phi2=100;}
    ]
 \addplot3[mantle=-90] (x,{2*x*cos(y)},{2*x*sin(y)});
 \path (1,0,-1) coordinate (p1) (1+delta,0,-1) coordinate (p1')
  (1,0,-2) coordinate (p2) (1+delta,0,-2) coordinate (p2');
 \addplot3[mantle=-90] (x,{x*cos(y)},{x*sin(y)});
 \draw[-stealth] (-1,0,0) -- (4,0,0);   
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0,-3) -- (0,0,3);   
 \addplot3[mantle=90] (x,{x*cos(y)},{x*sin(y)});
 \addplot3[mantle=90] (x,{2*x*cos(y)},{2*x*sin(y)});
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]